# Searching for patters from an input file against multiple files in a directory

Tags: grep

I'm looking for a way to use multiple patterns contained in a single file and search for those patterns in multiple files in a single directory. For instance, my input file might be:

input.txt:

```
2535664864
2535586396
2536640788
2535892886
2535876669
```

In the same directory, we have multiple filenames but I need to search for each of the above patters against multiple files with a specific naming convention. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the file containing your patterns into grep as following, to look for any of those pattern within multiple files you can specify like below:

```
grep -f pattern.file multiple.file*
```

if you only want match the patterns on an entire line not partiall match as above does, and for that you can add `-x` option to the grep.

Comment: So one other point that I really need to make on this is that the contents of the input file is quite critical. There are only 1390 patterns in that input file but I learned that there was a blank line at the bottom of that file.

With the blank line, there were 17253 results. When I remove that blank line, there are only 276. That is far closer to what we need. Syntax matters!  Thanks again for the assist.